# cumulative value with not all months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to make a histogram visual with power BI to display a monthly cumulative measurement for a year selected in the filter part.

I have 2 dimension :

For the visual I need to show the number of candidat by month but I got a problem with calculating cumulative value because in my measurement I don't have all months with values
I only have 3 monthes with values (jan : 250, sept : 98, dec : 734).
This is my measurement  : Mesure test = CALCULATE(SUM('Mission'[nbr candidat]))
I tried this fonction for cumulative measurement but nothing is showing :
PS 2.3.2 cumul = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([Mesure test], date[Date]))
Any help please

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like you're trying to use the date from the fact table (about the candidates) and not the date from the date dimension on your axis. Joins in DAX are OUTER joins (unless you're using INNERJOIN with CALCULATE etc). So you won't have months dropping out of your "axis". If you need a Calendar table, they're like white on rice. Look around for a minute and you'll find one. Or use something like

CALENDAR(
MINX('FactTable'[EventDate]),
MAXX('FactTable'[EventDate])
)
and then use ADDCOLUMNS to add Year, Month etc to that.
then you should have no problem with your running totals. Also, check out the running totals example on DaxPatterns.com (Ferrari & Russo's site).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the standard AdventureWorksDW file, but something like this should work:

YTD Total Sales = CALCULATE( SUMX('Sales',[Order Quantity] * RELATED('Product'[List Price]) ),
FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date]<=MAX('Date'[Date])))

I was wondering if I needed to include a filter for the selected year, but I have a slicer on my page for the year (dropdown, so I can only select one).

For grins, I created a column in my date table for

MonthYear = DATE(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]),1)

and graphing works a champ. I just use MonthYear for the X-Axis.